How do I power an LED and Buzzer with 9V Supply?
I am trying to add a buzzer and an LED to a circuit with a 9V power source. The LED has a forward voltage of 1.8V and a current draw of 2mA. The Buzzer has a rated voltage of 5V and a current draw of around 20mA. The solution does not have to be that power efficient, something simple would be best.
I think to just power the LED I would need a 3600 ohms resistor, and to just power the buzzer I would need a 200 ohms resistor. However, I do not know how to wire both to the same circuit, and how the components would effect each other.


What is being used to switch on the buzzer and the LED?

It will be a rain sensor connected to a NPN BC547 Transistor. When the rain sensor detects a drop it will allow the full current to flow from the collector pin to the emitter pin.
I linked a video freeze frame which contains the basic schematic. My version will be a PCB though: https://youtu.be/DNS1Jhx0MtU?t=37

Answer: just connect each load (the buzzer, and the LED) to the power source via its own separate resistor.  Select the resistor to give the required current.
Here is the schematic from your video link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNS1Jhx0MtU&t=37s

Below is my suggested design.
I estimated that the voltage at the emitter will be about 8V, but it would be best to measure it.  Select resistors to give the required current for each load.  The values here give about 20mA for the buzzer (shown as a speaker), and about 2mA for the LED, based on 8V appearing at the emitter of the NPN transistor.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
